# F-String Literal Not Printing kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

```
def myfunc (*args, **kwargs):
    print (args)
    print (kwargs)
    print (f'I would like {args[0]} {kwargs['food']}')
    #Example #2 print ('I would like {} {}'.format(args[0], kwargs['food']))

myfunc(10,20,30,fruit = 'orange', food = 'eggs', animal = 'dog')
```

When I execute the code above, I get an error that says:

SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '['

However, when I execute "Example #2" instead, I get the correct output:

I would like 10 eggs

What is wrong with my syntax when using f-string literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the same quotes surrounding the string in the string itself.  You are terminating the string early.

Use `"food"` not `'food'` or use triple single- or double-quotes like:

```
print (f'''I would like {args[0]} {kwargs['food']}''')
```

Comment: Expanding a little on this answer: you can also use double quotes on the outer f-string `f"I would like {args[0]} {kwargs['food']}"`

Answer (score 0):

When you use single quote inside of an f-string you need to wrap it in double quotes.
in your Example, you will need to replace as follows.

```
print (f'I would like {args[0]} {kwargs['food']}')

#replace with

print (f"I would like {args[0]} {kwargs['food']}")
```

Comment: This is essentially identical to the existing answer